# Ошибка CS0161 C#

Tags: c#, return

В коде возникает ошибка CS0161(не все пути кода возвращают значение)

Код:

```
public static string[] GetFilenames(string FolderPath)
{
    string[] FilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath);
    string[] FileNames = new string[FilePaths.Length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < FilePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        FileNames[i] = Path.GetFileName(FilePaths[i]);
        
        if(i == FilePaths.Length - 1)
        {
            return FileNames;
        }
    }
}
```

Понятно что когда-нибудь условие выполнится, но компилятор не понимает этого.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в этом куске коде, а в целом методе - он не возвращает значение. Если же это весь отрывок кода - просто за цыклом кинь ошибку: "throw new Exception("В цыкле что-то пошло не так и последний элемент не найден");"

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9939701/4928642 2. https://web.archive.org/web/20100712111650/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx 3. https://web.archive.org/web/20100810232326/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/12/absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absence.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно бросить исключение (которое не будет выброшено никогда), чтобы успокоить компилятор.

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    // Код
            
    if(i == X - 1)
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
throw new Exception("Вот сейчас очень неожиданно было");
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, непонятно, в чём вообще смысл данного куска кода. Он совершенно равнозначен такому коду (если вы не меняете `i` и/или `X` внутри цикла, что было бы очень плохим стилем программирования), при этом компилятор ругаться не будет и читается такой код легче:

```
for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    // Код
            
}
return Value;
```

Но в общем случае компилятор не обязан знать, что у вас будет происходить в процессе работы программы, он просто видит, что если `if` не сработает, то из функции ничего не вернётся, а поскольку `C#` строго типизированный язык, вы не можете в одной ветке кода что-то вернуть, а в другой ничего не вернуть. (Хотя, например, язык `Python` такое допускает, в этом случае в нём вернётся `None`, но он и не язык со строгой типизацией.)

Так что вам в любом случае надо сделать так, чтобы все ветки кода возвращали значение (либо бросали исключение).

Comment: вся проблема в том что X - ссылочный тип данных, а определяется ( = new) он в теле цикла.

Comment: @GREATDNG Абажжите, а как же тогда проверяется условие окончания цикла `i < X` если `X` до цикла не определено?

Comment: @GREATDNG А если вы имели в виду `value`, то ничего не мешает сделать `var value = null;` перед началом цикла.

Comment: Я изменил код на оригинал из программы. Прошлый пример имел ошибки в логике.

Comment: @GREATDNG Так теперь мой ответ ещё более актуален. В вашем `if`-е нет никакого смысла, компилятор правильно делает, что предупреждает, правда, не о той проблеме, о которой следовало бы :)

Comment: @GREATDNG Вы совершенно спокойно можете выкинуть `if` и перенести `return FileNames;` на момент после завершения цикла `for`.

Comment: @GREATDNG Хотя нет, если `FilePaths.Length` вдруг равен нулю, то цикл вообще не отработает и, возможно, вам в этом случае всё же нужно выкидывать исключение, если такого быть не должно и это проблема.